How can I edit the Taskbar text color without the use of 3rd party software?
I'm aware that system color settings affect the Taskbar and its text but, I prefer Light Mode which features dark text.
I use a transparent Taskbar that sometimes makes it difficult to see the time and system icons with certain backgrounds.
How do you edit the Taskbar text color without the use of 3rd party software? Is it possible to have the text invert background colors?

You might try High Contrast settings, or choose a darker background, at which point the icon text should change to white. That said, tools such as Open-Shell Menu allow complete control of icons and taskbar colors, degree of transparency, and even the Start Button image -- but that's a third party tool.
